# Override modal-popup.html file Magrnto 2.3.2

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.2, modal-popup

Override `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/modal/modal-popup.html` File Into Theme..

How To Override base/ folder file into theme ???

I m Try To Paste this file in to `theme/Magento_Ui/templates/modal-popup.html` But Not Working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder path is given wrong in your overide,It should be inside Web folder not templates

```
theme/Magento_Ui/web/templates/modal/modal-popup.html
```

Comment: let me check... 1+ reaponse

Comment: not working....

Comment: Have you done setup upgrade and content deploy?

Comment: yes follow all steps s:up , s:s:d or c:c

Comment: I have updated the answer just change template to templates

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: thank q its working

Comment: You are welcome